# How to set width of RatingBar programmatically in Android

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to change my `RatingBar` style programmatically. Anyone can help me how I change this style small how I can fill rating. I give you snapshot of current condition:

[image]

My code:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(Review.this);
ratingBar.setStepSize((float) 0.5);
ratingBar.setMax(5);
ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rating.get(i)));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your Rating Bar in `LinearLayout` and give height and width to this `LinearLayout`.

This `LinearLayout` should act as a parent of `RatingBar` and set the width and height of `RatingBar` to `wrap content`.

Also You can use

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to set the width and height of view at run time

```
LayoutParams params = null;
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 70;
params.width = 70;
button .setLayoutParams(params);
```

**If you want to use XML then above mentioned code is appropriate.**

Comment: It give a error :Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

you can set the small style of rating bar by java code

```
RatingBar ratingBar =
  new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
```

or using xml file

```
<RatingBar
  android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
  style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:numStars="5"
  android:isIndicator="false" />
```